# Create sticky form without inline php code?

Tags: php, html

So I have a sticky form created but the problem is that it is not "good practice" to use inline php code.

Example:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">First Name:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['first_name'])) echo $_POST['first_name']; ?>" >
            </div>
            <?php echo $input_errors['first_name']; ?>
        </div>
```

More specifically:

```
value="<?php if(isset($_POST['first_name'])) echo $_POST['first_name'];?>"
```

What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: What don't you like about it?

Comment: My instructor says it's spaghetti code and not good practice.

Comment: possibly store value in an variable and then only print there,while there is nothing bad in this according to me.

Comment: If you want to take the logic out of the HTML just do `$firstName = (isset($_POST['first_name'])) ? $_POST['first_name'] : '';` in the head of your document and then use `value="<?= $firstName; ?>"` in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any html/PHP mix. Then you can set a JavaScript variable.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9sLj4xj/1/)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Filled Variable:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name_1" id="first_name_1" placeholder="First Name 1" />
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Unfilled Variable:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name_2" id="first_name_2" placeholder="" />
    </div>
</div>

/*
var first_name = '<?= $_REQUEST['first_name']?>
*/
var first_name_1 = 'Bob';
var first_name_2 = '';

$('#first_name_1').val(first_name_1);
$('#first_name_2').val(first_name_2);
```

---

EDIT:

I use this type of technique with ajax calls on modular database driven websites. That way i cut down on redundant coding.